# Real targets with PHONY dependencies

Tags: makefile, dependencies

Trying to find an elegant method to solve some complex dependencies. I have something like the following in my Makefile:

```
.PHONY: FOO
FOO: foo
foo:
    build foo

.PHONY: BAR
BAR: bar
bar: FOO
    build bar
```

The idea here is that I want to abstract the real files (foo, bar) with phony targets (FOO BAR). In my real Makefile, of course, it is more complicated which is why the abstraction is important. The problem here, though, is by making phony target FOO a dependency for bar, then Make always tries to rebuild bar even if both foo and bar are up-to-date. This is apparently because it always treats FOO as out-of-date. But this behavior is not really correct.

So it seems I only have 3 options:
    1) Make bar directly dependent on foo. In my real Makefile it is more complicated and trying to specify the real files as dependencies is highly undesirable.
    2) Use variables in addition to all the phonies. This makes the whole Makefile more complex.
    3) Remove foo/Foo as a dependency from bar and add a recursive make of FOO as part of the rule in bar. This is very bad form.

Is there some more elegant solution that I am not aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I see why you want to make this abstraction at all.  One of the best parts of `make` is how it handles real targets and timestamps well.

Comment: Unless you can explain more clearly why you require the target to be PHONY I don't see how we can help.  What are you trying to achieve by making it PHONY?  What breaks or doesn't work correctly if you don't use PHONY?  The entire point of PHONY is to ensure that the recipe associated with the target is always run, so the idea that this behavior is "not really correct" is ... not really correct :-)

Comment: The file names are complex (sub-directories, long names, etc.). Using the file names directly in all of the rules makes things rather unreadable. From an end-user perspective, the targets become impractical to enter on the command line because of this complexity. I could choose to completely replace the PHONY targets with variables -- I suppose -- which would simplify the Makefile but you still have the same problem with the "make" command line (i.e. the the targets that the user has to specify are complicated).

Answer (score 4):

As you suggest, variables are what you need, and can actually help readability. They allow us to make the bar-file depend correctly on the foo-file, rather than on your user-friendly .PHONY target:

```
foo.file = horrendously/long/path/to/the/real/foo.file
bar.file = horrendously/long/path/to/the/real/bar.file

.PHONY: FOO
FOO: $(foo.file)
$(foo.file):
        touch $@

.PHONY: BAR
BAR: $(bar.file)
$(bar.file): $(foo.file)
        touch $@
```

And here we go:

```
$ make BAR 
touch horrendously/long/path/to/the/real/foo.file
touch horrendously/long/path/to/the/real/bar.file

$ make BAR
make: Nothing to be done for `BAR'.
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU make's answer to this situation is [order-only dependencies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-order_002donly-prerequisites). It allows you to provide ordering of targets without having the "out of date" relationship as well. From your question, it appears that this is what you are looking for.

So your makefile snippet from above would look like this:

```
.PHONY: FOO
FOO: foo
foo:
    build foo

.PHONY: BAR
BAR: bar
bar: | FOO
    build bar
```

This will allow foo to always be built before bar, but will not mandate that when foo is updated, that bar must be built. foo will only be built when `make BAR` is called and foo's files do not exist.

Comment: Nice. I have just used your suggestion in anger, in the case in which FOO was a genuine PHONY - that is, a target that does something important, but generates no file named FOO (or foo). I suspect that the order-only dependency doesn't work for Miguel, though, as it doesn't rebuild the bar file if foo is out of date.